# Why an android app renders different in emulator and my Galaxy M?

Tags: android, emulation, prototyping

My first design renders on emulator nicely. But when it comes to my physical device, some elements are not showing and the colors are also different...

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!--Material Colors-->
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>


    <!--Our Project Colors-->
    <color name="dark_green">#3FC1AF</color>
    <color name="light_green">#89DA91</color>
    <color name="red">#FFC5C5</color>
    <color name="white_green">#D6FFF9</color>
    <color name="gray">#373737</color>
</resources>
```

[In my phone the design shows different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIhFL.jpg)
[Emulator shows exact same output as the Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z01qQ.png)

Comment: Make sure your physical device is not in dark mode.

Comment: @JaswantSingh Thank you verymuch